# How to make const string from series[integers]

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v4

I am trying to print the value of mondayAll, and since it comes as a series of integers, I am taking the most recent value(mondayAll[0]). Still, this error happens:
`Cannot call 'string' with 'x'=series[integer]. The argument should be of type: const string;`

```
var int mondayLong = 0
var int mondayAll = 0
// ---------------------------

if(dayofweek == dayofweek.monday)
    mondayAll := mondayAll + 1
    if(close > open)
        mondayLong := mondayLong + 1

val = mondayAll[0]
text1 = "Monday All: " + string(val)
l1 = label.new(bar_index,high[0],text=text1)
label.delete(l1[1])
```

Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `str.tostring()`function instead.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My Script")
var int mondayLong = 0
var int mondayAll = 0
// ---------------------------

if(dayofweek == dayofweek.monday)
    mondayAll := mondayAll + 1
    if(close > open)
        mondayLong := mondayLong + 1

val = mondayAll[0]
text1 = "Monday All: " + str.tostring(val)
l1 = label.new(bar_index,high[0],text=text1)
label.delete(l1[1])

plot(close)
```